# Regexbuddy get matches without to much linefeeds

Tags: regex, regexbuddy

I'm using regexbuddy to get all matches from a text input [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrigy.png). This works fine except the issue that to much newlines [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7FdE.png) are added to output of the matches (because every single match is listed in a new line, see detailed output [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuJpC.png)). Is there an option or a workaround to avoid this?

Edit: My Regex is quite simple: \w*

Text input

[image: Text input]

Output
[image: Text Output]

Detailed Output
[image: Detailed Text Output]

Comment: Obviously, what is the regex you're using?

Comment: How exactly do you think anyone can help you when you show neither the raw input text nor the regular expression you use?

Comment: Sorry for my unsuficient information. I added the information.

Comment: Use `\w+`. `\w*` will match empty strings.